# Получаю ошибку "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable" при вызове "np.array()"

Tags: python, numpy

Не могу понять в чем дело? Хочу вывести процентиль заданных чисел:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) 
p = np.percentile(a, '50') 
print (p)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему 50 в кавычках?

Comment: Да и без них получаю ошибку:

Comment: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: У меня работает `[Dbg]>>> 3.0`

Comment: Похоже вы ввели переменную “np” (инициировав ее кортежем) и переписали тем самым модуль Numpy. Обратите внимание на то что ошибка вызвана командой np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

Comment: MaxU, спасибо вы верно определили:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспроизведение "ошибки":

```
In [8]: np.array = (1,2,3)

In [9]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3116b4661c0d> in <module>
----> 1 a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Вы переопределили метод `np.array()`, "переписав" его кортежем.

После этого команда:

```
np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

эквивалентна вызову:

```
In [13]: (1,2,3)([1,2,3,4,5])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1a146524a277> in <module>
----> 1 (1,2,3)([1,2,3,4,5])

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```